# How to return list of indices from pandas dataframe using another pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am using the [kaggle house price dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction/data), and I have the following code which calculates interquartile ranges

```
# bin by area
df['sqft_area_binned']=pd.cut(x=df['sqft_living'], bins=5)
q1 = df.groupby(['sqft_area_binned'])['price'].quantile(0.25)
q3 = df.groupby(['sqft_area_binned'])['price'].quantile(0.75)
iqr = q3 - q1
upper = q3 + 1.5*iqr
lower = q1 - 1.5*iqr
print(upper)
>>>
sqft_area_binned
(276.75, 2940.0]        946000.0
(2940.0, 5590.0]       1900000.0
(5590.0, 8240.0]       4332500.0
(8240.0, 10890.0]     10210500.0
(10890.0, 13540.0]    10410000.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Now I want to return a list of id's (first column in `df`) where `sqft_area_binned` is either *below*  the corresponding `lower` or *above* the corresponding `upper`.

For example, if a house (one row in `df`) has `sqft_area_binned=(276.75, 2940.0]` and `price` > 946000.0, then return `id`.

How is this possible, maybe using filtering or `.isin()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query = df.index[(df.sqft_area_binned == desiredBin) & (df.price > upperPriceBound)]
```